# Javascript/jQuery: Read data from Active directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, active-directory, ldap

Is it possible to read user information from Active directory using JavaScript / jQuery ? I am trying to read the location, manager name and other details from company LDAP.

How to read data from LDAP using JavaScript / jQuery ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using C# and was able to get the information . But not got any information / tried any code on how to proceed using client side

Comment: not possible using client side you need a server side coding. and you can use server side coding inside WEB-API and consume that API in client side

Comment: Saw a link - http://sirlagz.net/active-directory-with-javascript-examples/ . not sure what is used in GetObject method

Comment: http://ldapjs.org/ <- - - - - - @NegiRox

Comment: What framework is your application running on? (ASP.NET?) It sounds like you just need to pass the data from server-side to client-side (you don't need to contact AD from client-side)